# Creating a typesafe generic prop component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm attempting to create a generic component type that can be passed as part of props to another component, think a List component that can accept a number of different Header components.

```js
type PropsA = { text: string } & JSX.IntrinsicAttributes;
type PropsB = { text: string, num: number } & JSX.IntrinsicAttributes;

type GenericComponent<Props extends JSX.IntrinsicAttributes> = {
  Component: FC<Props>,
  props: Props,
}

type ComponentAorB = GenericComponent<PropsA | PropsB>;

// Works, TS can infer that Component and props have matching types
const Consumer: FC<ComponentAorB>
= ({ Component, props }) => <Component {...props} />;

// Lets create a real scenario:
const ComponentA: FC<PropsA> = ({ text }: PropsA) => (<div>{text}</div>);
const ComponentB: FC<PropsB> = ({ text, num }: PropsB) => (<div>{text}{num}</div>);

const AnotherConsumer = () => {
  const [generic, setGeneric] = useState<ComponentAorB>({
    Component: ComponentA,
    props: { text: "" }
  })

  setGeneric({
    Component: ComponentB,
//  ^ ERROR property "num" is missing in type...
    props: { text: "", num: 1 }
  });

  return <generic.Component {...generic.props}/>;
}
```

I had hoped TS would understand that if Component is `FC<PropsB>` props will always be `PropsB`, but it does not. Can I fix this by structuring the generic types differently, or is TS unable to infer the types in this kind of situation?

A variant of this is to declare ComponentAorB as `type ComponentAorB = GenericComponent<PropsA> | GenericComponent<PropsB>;` instead, which breaks in a different place but allows TS to infer the correct type in `setGeneric`.

I seem to end up creating an intersecting union while trying to avoid doing so.

In useState,

```js
// TypeScript interprets `ComponentAorB` as:
{
  Component: FC<PropsA> | FC<PropsB
  props: PropsA | PropsB
}

// I expect / want it to be interpreted as:

{
  Component: FC<PropsA>
  props: PropsA
} | {
  Component: FC<PropsB>
  props: PropsB
}

// Which works with setGeneric, but moves the error to the return statement instead:

return <generic.Component {...generic.props}/>;
//      ^ ERROR property "num" is missing in type...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useState` is not fit for the task because the `setState` callback is typed by the React team and they did not anticipate your use case, which is to relate a portion of a type (`props`) with another (`Component`) in the state.

Trying to rely on a discriminated union would just be a world of pain. For control flow analysis to make sense of it, you would need to add a discriminant and branch over it at runtime even though the branches are equivalent, which is both unmaintainable and wasteful.

I suggest you make your code truly generic by not mentioning `PropsA` and `PropsB` directly or indirectly in `Consumer` and `useState`. You will also have to patch the return type of `useState`

I'm calling your `{ Component: FC<Props>, props: Props }` type a "bundle" in the rest of this answer for clarity.

```js
type GenericBundle<Props extends JSX.IntrinsicAttributes> = {
  Component: FC<Props>,
  props: Props,
}

const Consumer = <P extends JSX.IntrinsicAttributes>
  ({ Component, props }: GenericBundle<P>): JSX.Element =>
    <Component {...props} />;

const useBundle = <P extends JSX.IntrinsicAttributes>(init: GenericBundle<P>) =>
  useState(init) as [
    GenericBundle<P>,
    <S extends JSX.IntrinsicAttributes> (value:
      | GenericBundle<S>
      | ((prevState: GenericBundle<S>
    ) => GenericBundle<S>)) => void
  ]

const AnotherConsumer = () => {
  const [bundle, setBundle] = useBundle({
    Component: ComponentA,
    props: { text: "" }
  })

  setBundle({
    Component: ComponentA,
    props: { text: "" }
  });

  setBundle({
    Component: ComponentB,
    props: { text: "", num: 1 }
  });

  setBundle({
    Component: ComponentC,
    props: { text: "", bool: false }
  });

  setBundle({
    Component: ComponentB,
    // @ts-expect-error: missing `num`
    props: { text: "" }
  });

  setBundle({
    Component: ComponentC,
    // @ts-expect-error: missing `bool`
    props: { text: "" }
  });

  setBundle({
    Component: ComponentA,
    // @ts-expect-error: excess property `num`
    props: { text: "", num: 1 }
  });

  return <bundle.Component {...bundle.props}/>;
}

type PropsA = { text: string } & JSX.IntrinsicAttributes;
type PropsB = { text: string, num: number } & JSX.IntrinsicAttributes;
type PropsC = { text: string, bool: boolean } & JSX.IntrinsicAttributes;

const ComponentA: FC<PropsA> = ({ text }: PropsA) => (<div>{text}</div>);
const ComponentB: FC<PropsB> = ({ text, num }: PropsB) => (<div>{text}{num}</div>);
const ComponentC: FC<PropsC> = ({ text, bool }: PropsC) => (<div>{text}{bool}</div>);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQLABQokscA3nAGIDCANHAK6osAZRjIYWOAF84REuUp4YtOvRgBPMBIDiWAHZYowXACE+ugCYAbLAB4ACsTDosAD3EX0AKSEANAHQAkrowhrqoRgCCMCHAAEZ84qgAfHAAvKz0cHCcJJD6wQBcHJz2jsncmXBgZUUOEE4VdJL09LgQYfA5YXwgBmlw9nCu7uZevoHBoeG4UTHxiUmVABRsOeDtejC81fXokkU6+oYmZla2dkkAlEXe-gCi1r3BaYt0WVk2a3mbrH5-O05pAB6JIAbhadDaHX4glMFms-UGwz0ozgtwmMTCkWihnmWGSS2AumAMAOegMRjhZ3sVxelQEwlE4kJxJglxQ6AA2pUsocKSd4ecko13gMhEM3Cixv4gpjprNcQl8SklgA3ZCWPhYAo894AHzgfOOVOsNiEr1FWQNSyW1SwqpEYm1hvJxtOpvNuvZqRSRsp7ts5su3pSqogwHMlQAuhCoah4BFdBAYAALAxdVA9PrpJYhjJvOBx+Cc+KC3iCGAmrBR-oMqsrXVfDaFbK5ZswCIi94A1BFNjiNxFABEQ6klUklwhWQr9ZYjbb+VJrfWi87up7fbgA6XI7HBYn4JUBZnAYbBayTcXRUvm2MXayG9YW+Gw6HvF0PSKAEY91kD1O4BPQUz1FG8WzAmAeHXGon23V9eFiCAIEsIoCA1QRfykS5D0qICzhA94IOvBdb3vOAgSBOAAAEYFQABaVxNHwBioGIKAihAYBUHCXQAHM4AAAw-EABOg3ZNzguBd2afdsIAvDrAIi8SPAlTILIijqNohiXCYmAWLYjiuJ4-iBMQ5DRPPKoYP7F8pNHGS-zko9pywStTznKyiOXb5gjXKzNJo+jGKwZiDEMiVcHxdAAQMdRBOEyzRUfWzB3s99PzgH9HKwnCC0oGA+CgXQBlLM4-Ag34-jK6w-B7SQQUPGTVA0CQ6icCJ+lSpd41CfjpAAMjRcZZSmbE5iVVBD3UTQ4Ha1BjC6580t6oleIykAimE2I+kG4aZUmIl5RxOJJum1q5rKTglsk1a+IQpCULgczrGQEq9vRUajvGxVEjyosfPbCIii4UpdgiFIc26qRajKCI8yWGxzGAVUkhYbdJBsIFkdR5yAYg4wQZKebjEhuAVmWrY4GEmHLt2YwEaRlG0YxlhhMx7Hmbx9p40BxdOCJsGnE4MmKe3B7kNp+bOEZnGWeGSQWBejm5ewoA)

Note that I did not make `S` extend `P` in `useBundle` but that's something you may want to do. Here `PropsB` and `PropsC` are subtypes of `PropsA` so it's not a problem that `bundle` is of type `GenericBundle<PropsA>`. You could also pass a type parameter to `useBundle` that is wider in case a different initialiser does not sufficiently overlap with your other types. It would also be possible to constrain it to a list of components if that's really what you need.

```js
type UnionToIntersection<T> =
   (T extends any ? (a : T) => void : never) extends
      ((a: infer R) => void) ? R : never

type Exclusive<P, S> = {
   [K in keyof S]: K extends keyof UnionToIntersection<P> ? S[K] : never
}

const useBundle = <P extends JSX.IntrinsicAttributes>(init: GenericBundle<P>) =>
  useState(init) as [
    GenericBundle<P>,
    <S extends P & Exclusive<P, S>> (value:
      | GenericBundle<S>
      | ((prevState: GenericBundle<S>
    ) => GenericBundle<S>)) => void
  ]

const AnotherConsumer = () => {
  const [bundle, setBundle] = useBundle<PropsA | PropsB>({
    Component: ComponentA,
    props: { text: "" }
  })

  setBundle({
    //@ts-expect-error: ComponentC  doesn't extends FC<(PropsA | PropsB) & Exclusive..
    Component: ComponentC,
    // @ts-expect-error: `bool` is `never`
    props: { text: "", bool: false }
  });

  return <bundle.Component {...bundle.props}/>;
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQLABQokscA3nAGIDCANHAK6osAZRjIYWOAF84REuUp4YtOvRgBPMBIDiWAHZYowXACE+ugCYAbLAB4ACsTDosAD3EX0AKSEANAHQAkrowhrqoRgCCMCHAAEZ84qgAfHAAvKz0cHCcJJD6wQBcHJz2jsncmXBgZUUOEE4VdJL09LgQYfA5YXwgBmlw9nCu7uZevoHBoeG4UTHxiUmVABRsOeDtejC81fXokkU6+oYmZla2dkkAlEXe-gCi1r3BaYt0WVk2a3mbrH5-O05pAB6JIAbhadHUmjgAFVdMB2gAVCBBcRQQT4BG6GyIlLpJaIoZuPSjFC6NRwAD8cCWyDgRURlxecAAbhBgOZ6XB9CyDEzhiT0EtaUVgLoCH0MEzUik2RymdSMFyeQYIVCJHcXLhLAJgLz7LwhHjWABtADScDFcAA1lg1BACHAhABdIoWgUeG12h2w+FIlHBAwYmBY+wpalCc3O5VYXlQZoqOhtDr8QSmCzWfqDD2k24TGJhSLRQzzLDJJZi4AwA56AxGdNnMPS15ZATCUTiCvwmBMtBwE2VLKHOsnDPnJKNd4DIREkboOxwABkcE12t1+rshqSKSWLOQOqwBUH7wAPnBh8cG9YbEbj1kz8LqrGRGJD+fa5fTtfb293s330c9ZfrYRqXP+crmJUzoQsmqDwBEugQDAAAWBhdKgPR9Pi-4sJUsHwCa8RjrwggwFeWDRukbbkaUuwRHAZ51E4xhJCsx5fBshTZLknEwBEk7vACqBFGw4huEUABEElSJUkiXBCWSkeRbG-lkHH5NW3HrBp-HHkJIlwGJmlSTJv5yeCiaKVgZHASpU7qZsRQOcExgCVk+msIZwySRJvC6D0RQAIymVk5kKXASm2bhqlwECQIAAIwKgAC0riaPgqVQMQUBOTxGmcFk5gQGWuhkPAOboFwNhLExqD0YxZTGEyy6rjq4QbmU9VwLVrndWUnDbuxeWOVp3zBDwx5xXAiUpWlWAZQY2VFAABrEEAQJYy2Wugy0qlAy16TUnlGT5vBrRtRQEPugghVIlwWZUkVjnZ7zOZpb2uZNQLTUlqUuOlMCZUtcAgMAqDhLoADmcC7T0B0xR5oneXAJkJqF93hU9ZwvWpw1cW9ukxVNM1-QDQPQEUri4GW6AAgY6gw-5IDw1OiNeeJKO+dyAVwMFaN3Q9v6UDAfBQLoAxEWcfhvb8fyS9YfhCZIIIWQmqgaBItX0ekSMc3BoTQ9Iy55qiUxFnMCRlhZ6p9bsxj9Lrmn62KkN+TzTOxH0RtwCbkxitMswlpbqDWxrttOAVOvs07Bau3A52WEUCc4OL3u+wWAfFnEweC-ho28RERRVVrxorNHUi1J1-5LDY5h6kkLBGZINhAnXLJXBZecfUXJQ9aXjtu6Q+zh6gTXMjXbcN03LBM83rf1xjSbtHB+f5T3tER-30dnetlgVyPnDV7X9eN8MkgsAnc+T-dQA)